# join three table in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select

i have three table to join in select query .. this query not working

```
select policy_master.POLICY_REFER ,policy_master.CLIENT_NAME ,policy_master.ADRESS ,policy_master.POLICY_CLASS ,policy_master.POLICY_PRODUCT ,policy_master.EXECUTIVE_NAME ,policy_master.COMM_DATE ,
policy_master.EXPIRY_DATE ,policy_master.RENEWAL_DATE ,policy_master.GROSS ,policy_master.FED ,policy_master.FIF ,policy_master.STAMP_DUTY ,policy_master.PERMIUM ,policy_master.DESCRIPTION, 
POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.INSURER_NAME,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.POLICY_NUMBER,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.P_SHARE,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.G_PREMIUM,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.BROKER_P,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.LEVY,
POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.LEVY,POLICY_SUBAGENT_DETAIL.SUBAGENT_NAME,POLICY_SUBAGENT_DETAIL.BUSSINES_SHARE,POLICY_SUBAGENT_DETAIL.COMM_P,POLICY_SUBAGENT_DETAIL.COMM_VALUE
from POLICY_MASTER INNER JOIN POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL 
on policy_master.policy_refer = POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.POLICY_REFER and
policy_master.policy_refer = POLICY_SUBAGENT_DETAIL.POLICY_REFER;
```

Please tell me what i should do

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and follow the instructions!

Comment: You only `JOIN`ed 2 tables, add the 3rd one, too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the answer I've removed all explicit columns and replaced them with `select *`.

You have only joined two tables. You are refering to `policy_subagent_detail` table inside a join to `policy_insurer_detail` (but you're not joining the subagent details table). You should join this table and specify joining conditions in order to be able to retrieve columns from it (as you did in your column list near `select` keyword).

I've also added table aliases to make your code shorter.

```
select *
from POLICY_MASTER pm
inner join POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL pid on 
  pm.policy_refer = pid.POLICY_REFER
inner join POLICY_SUBAGENT_DETAIL psd on -- added join
  pm.policy_refer = psd.POLICY_REFER
```

Comment: Kamil G.,, your query is working but there is one issue ... POLICY_MASTER is master table and other are detail , POLICY_MASTER have 1 row and other have two, in result i have 4 rows ... , why  ?

Comment: This is how joins work. We are joining master table with insurer detail which in your case produces 1*2 = 2 rows. We are also joining master table with subagent detail which produces 1*2 = 2 rows. To make all combinations available, we need 2*2 = 4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

do inner join of the third table required you missed iton the from clause . thats it .OR you can use where clause like

```
from table1 a,table2 b,table3 c
where a.colname= b.colname and
            b.colname=c.colname.
```